# how can I view Console Output whilst my Unit Tests are running in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

How can I view Console Output whilst my Unit Tests are running?  I'm using the Visual Studio 2008 unit testing framework.  So I know that after a test is finished I can go to the results page for the test and click on output, however I'm after a way that I can effectively watch the console output for tests as the unit tests are executed.

EDIT - Interested in a specific answer for VS out of the box (i.e. without having to buy a plugin)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message");
```

To output to the "Output" tab while the unit test is running.

If you are using Console.Out.WriteLine("Message") then this will only show up at the end of the test run, as you mentioned.

I have used the following to give me both runtime messages and the end of test result output:

```
private void TestTrace(string message)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement on [dodgy_coder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788860/364818), that let's you use the variadic syntax of `Console.WriteLine` with a format statement with an arbitrary length list of objects after it.

```
    private void TestTrace(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(message,args));
        Console.Out.WriteLine(message,args);
    }

    void ex()
    {
        TestTrace("foo {0} {1}",bar,zzyzx);
    }
```

Note that you *must* run in Debug mode. In Release mode, the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` messages are suppressed.

Comment: Is there a way to get these msgs in release mode (run mode) ? Everything that I have tried is writing to test output in test explorer in VS and not to runtime output in main output window.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TDD plug in like ReSharper orTestDriven.net

Comment: I'll have a look thanks - is the idea that it would still be using the MS unit test framework?

Comment: Yes, TestDriven suports MSTest out of the box, and ReSharper may also..if not there is a plug in for it.

Comment: BTW know if my question navy be solve within VS without having to buy a plugin

Comment: Not sure, if it does it would only be for MSTest, check whatever built in runner VS has. We use NUnit so a plug in is a must. BTW, I cant live without ReSharper. Its for more than just unit testing. I highly recommend it